# Why my ubuntu 32-bit can support 6G RAM?

Tags: ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 32bit on my 6G RAM desktop, but it seems it can support 6G RAM.

I execute 'free -m', the command shows the total memory is 6G. does 11.10 come along with a patch for large memory support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you use PAE-kernel http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique called *Physical Address Extension* (PAE) that allows 32bit processors and 32bit operating systems on 64bit processors to use more than 4GB RAM. Depending on the actual kernel configuration Linux make can use of PAE.

Be aware that although your operating system might be able to use more memory, the memory a single process can use is generally still limited to 4GB (minus kernel address space).

Comment: The official site of Ubuntu recommends 32bit, I guess there's some problem with their 64bit dist, that's why I installed 32bit. and I didn't find a spec from ubuntu.com that states PAE is enabled by default. based on my case, it seems it IS enabled.